# Zorn´s Lemma, a prove that a subset A induces a partition of each line in the plane

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I´ve just started with Zorn´s Lemma and I've been having a hard time trying to prove something using Zorn´s Lemma.
The problem says:

> Show that there exists a subset $A$ of the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that:
>
> 1. Any $3$ points of $A$ do not belong to the same line.
> 2. Each point of $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ belongs to a line that passes through two points of $A$.
>
> Verify that $A$ induces a partition of each line in the plane

Comment: I'm not sure what it means by "Verify that $A$ induces a partition of each line in the plane". Do you have any insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal L$ be a set of all lines on $\Bbb R^2$. Let $\mathcal A$ be a family of all subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ satisfying the first condition:
$$\mathcal A=\{A\subset \Bbb R^2:\forall_{L\in\mathcal L}\, \#(L\cap A)<3\}.$$
It's a nonempty set ordered by the inlusion. Consider any chain $\mathcal B\subset \mathcal A$, that is a subfamily that is linearly ordered. Let $B=\bigcup \mathcal B$.

It turns out that $B\in\mathcal A$. Indeed, take any $L\in\mathcal L$. We have to prove that $\#(L\cap B)<3\}$. Assume  the contrary, that is there are three disctinct points $b_1,b_2,b_3\in L\cap B$. Then $b_i\in B_i$, $i=1,2,3$, where $B_i\in \mathcal B$. Since $\mathcal B$ is a chain, one of the sets $B_i$, say $B_3$, is greater then others, i.e. $B_1,B_2\subset B_3$. Therefore $b_1,b_2,b_3\in B_3\in\mathcal B\subset \mathcal A$. Therefore
$$3>\#(L\cap B_3)\geq \#\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}=3,$$ a contradiction.

Since $B$ is an upper bound and $\mathcal B$ is any chain, the assumptions of Kuratowski-Zorn's Lemma are satisfied. Therefore there exists $A\in\mathcal A$ that is maximal.

Maximality implies the condition 2. is satisfied. Indeed, take any $x\in \Bbb R^2\setminus A$. Then $A\cup\{x\}$ cannot be in $\mathcal A$, so there are two points $a_1,a_2$ in $A$  such that $a_1,a_2,x$ are colinear.